# C# How to ignore Xml Header in request to WebApi?

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-web-api, xml-serialization

I'm creating a new Route to my WebApi, which should receive the following XML throught a HTTP POST

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<AcquireKeysRequest>
  <version>2</version>
  <content>
    <id>MTV</id>
    <type>VOD</type>
  </content>
  <protection>
    <protection-system>
      <type>DASH-CENC</type>
      <system-id>urn:mpeg:dash:mp4protection:2011</system-id>
    </protection-system>
  </protection>
  <key-timing>
    <position>0</position>
  </key-timing>
</AcquireKeysRequest>
```

I've mapped it through the framework, using the following Model:

```
public class AcquireKeysRequest
{
    public int Version { get; set; }
    public Content Content { get; set; }
    public Protection Protection { get; set; }
    public KeyTiming KeyTiming { get; set; }
}
public class Content
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

public class Protection
{
    public ProtecionSystem ProtectionSystem{ get; set; }
}

public class ProtecionSystem
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string SystemId { get; set; }
}

public class KeyTiming
{
    public int Position { get; set; }
}
```

When I receive the request without the header

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

The mapping works just fine, but when I add the header, it breaks.
**How can I ignore it?**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("{instanceId}")]
    public object AcquireKeyRequest([FromUri]int instanceId, AcquireKeysRequest xml)
    {
       //SomeLogicHere
    }
```

P.S: I know that the names in the Model and in the XML are diferent, I fixed in my code already.

Answer (score 0):

Within your MVC Web API project please add the following package via NuGet:
**Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml**

Then in your startup.cs. Adapt the following to generally enable XML serialization and deserialization.

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
    services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
       options.Filters.Add(new ProducesAttribute("application/xml"));
    }).AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
 }
```

Finally create a Get and Post Method withing a controller and try it out. For me both cases works. With or without the xml-tag.

```
 [HttpGet]
 public AcquireKeysRequest Get()
 {
     AcquireKeysRequest req = new AcquireKeysRequest();
     req.KeyTiming = new KeyTiming() { Position = 2 };
     req.Protection = new Protection()
     {
         ProtectionSystem = new ProtecionSystem() {
              SystemId = "wkow", Type = "type"
         }
     };
     req.Version = 2;
     req.Content = new Content() { Id = "id", Type = "type" };
     return req;
 }

 [HttpPost]
 public void Post([FromBody]AcquireKeysRequest value)
 {
 }
```

I hope i could help out.

Cheers

Comment: Hi @Hadou.
My WebApi is not .NetCore, is .NetFramework 4.6.2
I did not try yet, but I'm guessing this should only work for .NetCore, am I wrong?

Comment: I do not think it makes a difference in this particular case. But try it out.. sry.